# Low FPS on Android emulator

Tags: android, windows, emulation, frame-rate

First of all, you need to know that I have a very powerful computer so that's not the problem.

I tried making a black screen without anything on it but an FPS counter, with OpenGL and Canvas, but the app doesn't go over 10-11 FPS.

I am just lost, I don't know what the problem is, I checked and it's not the render or the update function...

thanks for the help.

I am on windows 7 64 bit BTW.

Comment: Are you using the intel atom image?

Comment: I am using API 8 for Android 2.2, and if I understood correctly it is only for API 15

Comment: Then you have to rely on the emulator emulating an arm chip which is REALLY slow.  You can, of course, just run API 8 only code on an API15 device ..

Answer (score 2):

8 years later and i have the answer.

open the AVD manager, scroll down to emulated performance, change it from "Automatic" to "Hardware - GLES 2.0", if still not performing show the advanced settings and set it to "Cold boot" this changed it from like 8-12 fps to a solid 30 fps non stop.

Answer (score 0):

I'm more inclined to say that it is a fault of the Emulator than your system. It is extremely slow for me as well, even doing general app debugging. Not surprised on your frame rate. The Intel x86 Image might make a difference, but I usually don't see much improvement even with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can create x86 virtual machine.
See

[Android-x86 - Porting Android to x86](http://www.android-x86.org/)

[ISO image](http://code.google.com/p/android-x86/downloads/list)

Comment: If I run a virtual machine how ca i program in eclipse? you can minimize it or something? (sorry for my stupidness)

Comment: You must find out IP of virtual machine and then for example  C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb connect Your_machine_IP

Comment: To find out IP swithch your Virtualbox Android to console by alt+f1. Then use command netcfg, remember the IP. Then use Alt+F7 to go back to GUI. That is all.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that I get better performance out of the Emulator when I set the processor afinity to all through Windows Task Manager

Answer (score 0):

Here are some tips which can speed up the emulator significantly :

- **Give 1GB of RAM** (or even more) to your AVD. Don't try to emulate the amount of RAM of a real device, it is generally useless and can amazingly slow down the emulator.
- **Emulate Android 2.3.3**, which boots and runs faster on the emulator than the previous and next versions (by the way, *never emulate Android 2.1 or 2.2* if you use SQLite databases. The SQLite implementation was very slow even on real devices).
- **Don't use high screen resolutions and densities** unless for final testing. Use the smallest resolution available and set the LCD density to something low (in the mdpi range).

Answer (score 0):

Well, this might not be an alternative for everyone but for me it's perfect! Use the [Bluestacks Player](http://bluestacks.com/). it runs Android 2.3.4 and is very fluent and fast. Sometimes even faster than a normal device. The only downsize is, that you can just test Apps on the API Level 10 and just on one screen size, but it's perfect just for testing if it's working or not. Just connect the Player with the `adb` by running

```
adb connect 127.0.0.1
```

(Its always the same IP adress)